# Getting TypeError when trying to use jquery plugin, can't figure out why

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html5boilerplate

After much searching still stuck. Here's what I got:

plugin (just for reference, not really necessary for question): https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer

using html5bp so at bottom of my page I have the following code:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/vendor/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"</script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main-ck.js"></script>
```

in plugins.js I copied the plugin source:

```
;(function($) {
    $.timer = function(func, time, autostart) {...
   ...
})(jQuery);
```

but when I try to setup as per instructions (this code is after js includes, like in main-ck.js, which loads after plugins.js):

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    alert('This message was sent by a timer.');
});
timer.set({ time : 5000, autostart : true });
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: $.timer is not a function"

Its not wordpress or anything. $ is properly defined, but for the life of me I can't get the plugin function to go, so $.timer is not defined, scope issue?

Comment: One of your opening script tags is not closed: `<script src="js/vendor/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: @showdev
weird shows up for me, although that pane is horizontally scrolling so maybe its cut off for you?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iopwvnjs1ui52ds/Screenshot%202015-08-07%2015.50.37.png?dl=0

Comment: There should be a closing angled bracket after the end quote: `<script src="js/vendor/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>`. Compare with the "plugins" script tag below it.

Comment: Jesus christ I'm an idiot. I think that was it. /facepalm

Comment: @showdev thanks!! need to remember to eat. Should I delete the question then?

Answer (score 0):

I would close the following tag `<script src="js/vendor/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"</script>` to this

`<script src="js/vendor/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>`